# MySQL with asp.net MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mysql database on AWS. I want to connect to it using mysql client on my windows 10 and see which tables are in my db and what is data. Which mysql client I need to use. As we use SQL Server management studio for SQL server. Also, I want to use this database in asp.net MVC 4 using Entity framework. What packages/Addons I need to use? Someone suggested that I need to use this https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/.

The requirement is "All necessary DLL's should be installed using Nuget. That includes MySQL connector, MySQL.Data and Entity Framework."

Please help me on this.

Comment: A few that you can use 1) mysql workbench, 2)  Sqlyog or 3 ) heidisql etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps

> First Download MySQL Workbench

1. Use MySQL workbench for connecting your database to AWS.
2. Enter your Credentials to connect with you AWS database.

[image]

> Setting up Entity Framework

For doing that we need to download 2 NuGet packages.

[image: My SQL]

After adding this package you can connect to entity framework.

Comment: I installed these packages but I don't see My SQL in edmx wizard.

Answer (score 0):

A few that you can use

1) mysql workbench - "https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/"

2)  Sqlyog or https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog

3 ) heidisql https://www.heidisql.com/download.php
 etc